# Django models.Model class. models.CharField

Tags: python, django

This question might have been asked before, but sorry I couldn't find it so that is why I am asking

I want to understand the title `models.CharField()`

I understand that the we inherit the Model class from the module call models.

but then why not the class `Model.charfield()` as the method or function of Model

why models? which seams to me like a module and `CharField` seems like a class

its seems to me we are accessing a class from the models module.

example

```py
from django.db import models

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    permalink = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField('Last Updates')
    bodytext = models.TextField('Page Content', blank=True)
```

I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

Model inherit from models class ,
In django ORM Consider it more Like Model is to create a table in database and for each columns(here fields) in database we use models.corresponding_fields()

if you inspect db.models :

```
    (Many imports and )
    from django.db.models.query_utils import FilteredRelation

    # Imports that would create circular imports if sorted
    from django.db.models.base import DEFERRED, Model  # isort:skip
    from django.db.models.fields.related import (  # isort:skip
        ForeignKey, ForeignObject, OneToOneField, ManyToManyField,
        ManyToOneRel, ManyToManyRel, OneToOneRel,
    )


    __all__ = aggregates_all + constraints_all + enums_all + fields_all + indexes_all
    __all__ += [
        'ObjectDoesNotExist', 'signals',
        'CASCADE', 'DO_NOTHING', 'PROTECT', 'SET', 'SET_DEFAULT', 'SET_NULL',
        'ProtectedError',
        'Case', 'Exists', 'Expression', 'ExpressionList', 'ExpressionWrapper', 'F',
        'Func', 'OuterRef', 'RowRange', 'Subquery', 'Value', 'ValueRange', 'When',
        'Window', 'WindowFrame',
        'FileField', 'ImageField', 'OrderWrt', 'Lookup', 'Transform', 'Manager',
        'Prefetch', 'Q', 'QuerySet', 'prefetch_related_objects', 'DEFERRED', 'Model',
        'FilteredRelation',
        'ForeignKey', 'ForeignObject', 'OneToOneField', 'ManyToManyField',
        'ManyToOneRel', 'ManyToManyRel', 'OneToOneRel',
    ]
```

in short models in just `__init__.py` file contains all imports as a collection

for in depth details you can reads [django docs -  Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model)

Answer (score 0):

for any one else worried about this ...

i wasn't wrong to ask this ... and here i got my answer from django documentation page

click [here] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/)

Note

Technically, these models are defined in django.db.models.fields, but for convenience they’re imported into django.db.models; the standard convention is to use from django.db import models and refer to fields as models.Field.

this the answer: Technically, these models are defined in django.db.models.fields, but for convenience they’re imported into django.db.models